# Are there references to Meditation Techniques Practiced / Taught by Ven. Nanavira?

Tags: vipassana, reference-request, meditation-recommendation

[Ven. Nanavira](http://www.nanavira.org/) has written a lot on the Dhamma. I am looking for his material on meditation related topics.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to search a bit for some books by ven. Nanavira. I could only find this one [Clearing The Path](http://www.buddhanet.net/pdf_file/ctp_screen-view_v1.pdf). Maybe you can use it.

Comment: I have the book (Sinhala translation), but not exactly a meditation annual and very large to fully read.

Comment: Why is it so difficult to find meditational-related material from Ven. Nanavira? Did he not teach that area of buddhism?

Comment: I guess at that time meditation instruction were more given in Aranyas and mainly theoretical Dhamma was written as books.

Comment: Oh okay. I understand. I hope you find what you are looking for.